# Unable to run project after refactoring files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

While working on a project, I noticed that I had too many files unorganised and decided to arrange them by creating some packages and moving the files into different folders. However, after I did that, I got errors such as "unresolved reference" and "URL is not registered". I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project as well as restarting Android Studio but it doesn't work.

[image: Error screenshot here]

Comment: Without any code/source it's impossibile to help you

Comment: Sorry there @emandt, forgot to add screenshots.

Comment: Please post text as text, not images, which can't be copy-pasted (also, it's quite hard to read at that size).

Answer (score 0):

Go to **"File > Project Structure > Modules", click "add" and then click "android" and "apply/ok".**

It should solve your problem. Do comments If you get any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging)

As described here, you need something like this in you app level gradle

```
android {
sourceSets {
    res.srcDirs = [
                   'src/main/res/layout/manager',
                   'src/main/res/layout/navigation_tab',
                   'src/main/res/layout/staff']
}
```

After that, creat layout folder under each Dir, that you define here, and move all you xml files there. In my project it looking like this

[image]